# Composer create-project Fails With Any Project Type

Tags: composer-php

Something very strange is happening with my new installation of composer.  Every create-project I have tried (4 different projects), fails with an Invalid Argument error, "Could not find package with stability stable", or could not find with version x.x.

Tracing with -vvv, here is the execution pattern:  Request packages.json. Succeeds.  Request some [repository url]/[pkg name]/some json file.  Errors out no matter what I have tried.  Here are three specific examples.

```
composer create-project -n concrete5/composer test  -vvv 
[200] https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/packages.json
[404] https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/p2/concrete5/composer.json
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package concrete5/composer with stability stable.

composer create-project symfony/skeleton test  -vvv
[200] https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/packages.json
[404] https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/p2/symfony/skeleton.json
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package symfony/skeleton with stability stable.

 create-project drupal/recommended-project:8.x test  -vvv   
[200] https://packages.drupal.org/8/packages.json
[404] https://packages.drupal.org/files/packages/8/p2/drupal/recommended-project.json
 [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package drupal/recommended-project with version 8.x.
   (used repository packages.drupal.org/8)
```

If I try to load the requested .json file in a browser I get a 404 error, while I can load the packages.json file in a browser.  Looks like composer is sending requests for files that do not exist.

If I use the composer.json and composer.lock files from a working site, put it in an empty folder, then run composer install in that folder, it all installs as expected, but it gets the package from git site defined in the .lock file, not the repository.  If I remove the lock file and leave the just the composer.json file in the folder, I get a 404 error on every request for a .json file

```
[404] https://packages.drupal.org/files/packages/8/p2/drupal/core-recommended.json
[404] https://packages.drupal.org/files/packages/8/p2/drupal/core-project-message~dev.json
[404] https://packages.drupal.org/files/packages/8/p2/drupal/core-composer-scaffold~dev.json
[404] https://packages.drupal.org/files/packages/8/p2/drupal/core-recommended~dev.json
[404] https://packages.drupal.org/files/packages/8/p2/drupal/core-project-message.json
```

My platform is Windows 10 1904, php 7.3.21 on WAMP, composer 2.0.7 installed by their Windows installer.  All the above are with a brand new installation of composer.

I have tried clear-cache, composer diagnose, 4 different repositories, 4 different project types, various stability options, various global composer.json files.  I have re-installed wamp and composer.  I have downgraded to composer 1.10.x. Same error not matter what I tried. Spent hours looking on the internet.  This problem seems to be just my laptop otherwise the internet would have lit up, but I have tried everything I could find to resolve it.  Any idea what is causing this?  I have been updating all my Drupal sites manually on a tarball site, and I want to learn how to manage Drupal with composer starting from create-project drupal/recommended-project.

Comment: have you checked the json file to see what you have for the minimum stability? if the packages you are trying to install do not have an available package for your setting this is the message you will get instead, "Could not find package concrete5/composer with stability stable."

Comment: Please share more details - for example, why do you try to load the packages from `packagist.phpcomposer.com`? Would it work using the usual repositories?

Comment: I reinstalled wamp and Acquia Desktop.  Still did not work with v 2.0.7.  Downgraded composer to 1.10.17 and it worked!  Strange as I had tried that version before.  Today I tried 2.0.7 and everything works just fine.  Very strange, but 2.0.7 is lightening fast compared to 1.10.17.

Comment: After working fine for a day it suddenly started note being able to find packages.  I changed no configurations. composer create-project drupal/recommended-project cc   --no-install  -vvv shows error " Could not find package drupal/recommended-project with stability stable."  If I download the recommended project json and run install I get "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.".  I do not think the problem is with my laptop.

Comment: As to the questions above.  Why did I try packagist? Well, I am new do composer.  Nowhere in the Drupal pages "Using Composer With Drupal" or "Using Composer to Install Drupal and Manage Dependencies" did it mention setting the config repository to https://packages.drupal.org/8. Since those pages are for beginners, it seems like an important detail.  When I started I did not even have a config.json and fumbled through a bunch of errors just getting composer working.  As to the stabililty level, not sure what you mean as the code I tried is in my post and I did not specify a stability level.

Comment: Another point.  Look at the URLs in OP that returned a 404 error.  Are they valid? Are they the same URLs sent on your machine?  Bet they are.